# Node.js Rest call to a server that requires a certificate

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, pki

How do a make a rest call from Node.js to a server that requires a certificate for authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a custom [connection pool](https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback), for which you'll need to use a custom [Agent](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_agent).

---

Here's an example using the standard `https` module, straight [from the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback):

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  ...
}
```

---

And if you use [mikeal's request](https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback), you can set the custom agent in the `pool` option.

Comment: Why do I need to use a custom agent and a connection pool?

Comment: An Agent manages a socket pool and is used for instance to manage the maximum number of socket a process can open at once By default all HTTPS requests use the https.globalAgent.
As detailed [here](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) you can supply your own certificate information to any request... but if you use the global agent these options will be ignored. You'll then need to use a custom agent.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but could really use an example with code.